# error while exporting/print crystal report

Tags: asp.net, printing, crystal-reports, export, crystal-reports-2008

well i built a web application it works, now when i passed it to the server...
it didn't run, i passed .ddl to the another computer (where visual studio c# is installed too)
and it ran. in my computer where i programmed it, it could print, or export to pdf, word, excel, rpt etc.. now when in the server, images of crystal report dont load they appears as a (X) everyone! the image for print, for export.. tree view .. well all appears a X then... when i press on print or export, i got next error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HTTP Error 404 - Not Found. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0
```

I had read when i had another error when i was programming error is not of crystal report else it can be of adobe, whell i need a solution for that error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Crystal runtime engine for 2008.